# What are the uses of having binary files?

Tags: c, file-io

I am learning FileIO in C and was little confused with the binary files. My question is what is the use of having binary files when we can always use files in ASCII or someother format which can be easily understandable. Also in what applications are binary files more useful?
Any help on this really appriciated.Thanks!

Comment: programs are binary. Any possible binary code may be a program instruction for the CPU

Comment: Let me answer to your question with another question : Are you sure you could save without a big effort a C structure in a file if you only use ASCII mode ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All files are binary in nature. ASCII files are those subset of binary files that contain what can be considered to be 'human-readable' data. A pure binary file is not constrained to that subset of characters that is readable.

Answer (score 3):

Speed of access

Obfuscation

The ability to write native objects to file without creating big serialised files.

Answer (score 3):

ASCII is easily understandable by humans, but for many other purposes, it's more efficient and easier for the computer to store things in a binary format. For example, if you want to keep a sequence of integers, it's easier for the computer to read/write the 4 bytes it takes to represent an `int`, than it is to write out the ascii representation of the number, then parse it while reading.

Answer (score 2):

It is critically important that any byte value can be stored, for example programs are binary. Any possible binary code may be a program instruction for the CPU.

ASCII only stores 7-bit values, so there are half the possible values wasted.

Further, what would an integer be stored as?

The number 4294967295 can be stored in 4 bytes, 32 bits, but if it were stored in ASCII, as a number, it would require 10 characters. Further, it would require processing to convert it into the 32bit number. Neither of those things are good.

The 32bit number is a fixed size, so it is easy to get to the 234856th value in the file, just seek to position 4*234856.

If 32bit numbers are stored as ASCII, either they must always take 10 bytes, making the file 2.5 times bigger, or they are stored as variable size, making it virtually impossible to seek to a particular value without reading the whole file.

Edit:

Is is worth adding that (in normal use) a human can not see the data held in a file. The only way to examine the contents of files is by running programs which can read and use the data. So the convenience of a human is a small consideration.

In general, data is stored in the most convenient form for programs use, and the form is designed to fit the programs purpose. ASCII is a format designed for text edit programs to create human readable documents and support simple ways to display the text, which are limited to English letters, numbers and some punctuation. When we want to support all human written language, ASCII is far too limited.

I believe we have over one million characters to represent human written languages (and some other pictures), and we have not yet got characters for all human languages.

UTF-8 is a way to represent the written characters we have so far, as multiple bytes. UTF-8 uses 8bit encoding, which is beyond the range of ASCII.

Comment: +1..thx for good explanation. you have again made me to think :)

Answer (score 1):

Think of a binary file as a true representation of data to be interpreted directly by a computer program and not to be read by humans. It would be a lot of overhead for a program to write out data, whether ascii or numeric in an ascii format. Most likely, the programmer would have to invent a protocol for writing arrays, structs, and scalars out into a file in ascii form, so they could be human readable and also be read back in by the program and converted back to binary form.

A database table is a good example. Whether or not there are text or numeric fields in the table, the database manager reads and writes that data in binary format. It is easier to write out, read in, and then convert as needed to display any data you can read.

Perception gave a great answer I had never considered before. All data is binary and ascii is a subset. That answer made me think of ftp and setting the mode to ascii or binary. If I'm shuttling Windows binaries being stored on a Linux system, I tell ftp to transfer them as binary. That means, don't interpret as an ascii file and add \cr at the end of each line. There are even times I'll transfer .csv and .txt data as binary, because I know Windows Excel knows how to interpret those non-DOS files.

Answer (score 0):

I would not want to write a program that had to encode/decode images, or audio files, or GIS data, or spacecraft telemetry, or <fill in the blank> as ASCII.